# IntelliJ IDEA parpadea a cada rato

Tags: intellij-idea

Mi IDE preferido para codificación en Java y una que otra tecnología desde hace muy poco empieza a parpadear a cada rato la pantalla no se porque, he intentando mirar soluciones en YouTube, Google hasta volver a instalar IntelliJ IDEA e incluso el JDK de Java y no se soluciona lo cual se me hace raro ya que esto no me pasaba antes

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor

Comment: Toda la pantalla? Sólo la ventanita de IntelliJ? Otras ventanas de otros programas también? Entiendes que estamos a ciegas tratando de imaginar a qué te refieres? :)

Comment: @Alfabravo solamente la ventana de IntelliJ IDEA, voy a tratar de grabar para tener pruebas pero es complejo

Comment: Realmente cae en el espacio de cosas como deshabilitar los plugins que tengas e ir reiniciando y revisando si mejora... o reiniciar tu equipo y ver si hubo un cambio de controladores o algo...

Comment: @Alfabravo ya he hecho eso varias veces y no se me ha solucionado

Answer (score -1):

### Opción 1

Puede que estés aplicando algún tipo de escalado (scaling) o zoom a la pantalla donde pintas la ventana de IntelliJ. EL OS puede no ser muy bueno para actualizar el contenido de la ventana en esas condiciones; quitar ese zoom o escalado y dejar todo al 100% puede ayudar

### Opción 2

Otra opción es que, según [esta solución en el foro de JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006784180-Flickering-Flashing-Refreshing-UI-), la cosa puede ser una característica nueva de Windows MPO (multiplane overlay support) (si es que estás sobre Windows), creando un reg file nuevo que aplique este cambio al registro

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Dwm]
"OverlayTestMode"=dword:00000005
```

**Nota**: Este tipo de cambios los haces bajo tu cuenta y riesgo, entendiendo las posibles consecuencias de modificar el registro de windows.

### Opción 3

Si estás sobre OSX, es posible que hayas chocado con [un bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-304990).